# CKFinder image upload error

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am new to CKFinder with CKEditor in asp.net,
I am getting following error when i try to open file manager with Browse from Server button click,

Please find error details in following image [image]

Please help me get through this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably figured this out by now, but this occurs when your CKFinder path is invalid. double check your path.